# how use html view/partial to pdf view with wicked_pdf gem?

Tags: ruby, pdf, wicked-pdf

```
def foo    
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render layout: 'application' }
    format.pdf { 
      render pdf: 'foo', layout: 'pdf'
    }
  end
end
```

if I put only `hello world` in `foo.pdf.erb` it works !

but now if I want use a html view to iterate on my model (from DB) like :

```
<p>hello world</p>    
<%= render @foo.chapters.order(number: :asc) %>
```

it doest works, the page stay grey, no error in log...

if i comment this line, `hello world` works again.

So the issu is about using html partial : how can we use the normal html view in pdf view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue in [this commit](https://github.com/unixmonkey/wicked_pdf_issues/commit/66d7fb289259f7bba96fcb4afea048a9dd3602f0) of the [Wicked PDF issues project](https://github.com/unixmonkey/wicked_pdf_issues/) and was successful in accomplishing what you show here, however there is a minor caveat.

Using the Rails model rendering shorthand:

```
# assuming @books = Book.all or some collection of Book objects
<%= render @books %>
```

It will try and render that collection with the extension of the request.

Meaning, for an html request, it will attempt to render the template at:

```
app/views/books/_book.html.erb
```

And for a PDF request, it will attempt to render

```
app/views/books/_book.pdf.erb
```

I worked around this by renaming my partial to:

```
app/views/books/_book.erb
```

So it will be used regardless of an HTML or PDF request.

If that doesn't work in your situation, you can create a new PDF partial, that renders the HTML one like this:

```
# app/views/books/_book.pdf.erb
<%= render partial: '/books/book',
      formats: [:html],
      locals: { book: book } %>
```